# In my iPhone integrating Facebook app but when i post on my wall my friend unable to share what should i do?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I using facebook integrate for one of my iOS application it share quote. But problem is that when quote post on my timeline my friends not able to share just "Like" and "Comment". I want share to please see attach screenshots
so whats the best solution for that is there problem in my FB app or I've to do code for that in iOS.

[Screenshot of FB](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/newuploads/pnsoo.png)

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I checked your screenshot. That looks like fb "like post" basically. Since no one can't share this post. I would suggest you to use latest ios fb sdk 3.1.1 and then integrate that FB sdk with your ios app. Then use the following code

For ios 6 and later use ios 6 native fb post method:

```
if(NSClassFromString(@"SLComposeViewController") != nil) {

        UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
        app.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

        SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

        SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler myBlock = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){
            if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled) {

                NSLog(@"\nCancelled");                
            } else
            {
                NSLog(@"\nDone");
            }

            [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
        };
        controller.completionHandler =myBlock;

        [controller setInitialText:FB_POST_FEED_INITIAL_TEXT_MSG];
        [controller addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:BITLY_VIEW_LINK]]; // youtube video link

        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];
}
```

otherwise use this FB sdk method:

```
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:
     ^(FBSession *session,
       FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
         switch (state) {
             case FBSessionStateOpen:
                 //first shows the hud view then initiating the post message feed process
                 [self postFBMessageOnUserWall];
                  break;
             case FBSessionStateClosed:
                 //need to handle
                 break;
             case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
                 //need to handle
                 break;
             default:
                 break;
         }
     }];


-(void)postFBMessageOnUserWall {
    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             FB_POST_FEED_INITIAL_TEXT_MSG, @"name", BITLY_VIEW_LINK, @"link", nil];

     [FBRequestConnection
      startWithGraphPath:@"me/feed"
      parameters:params
      HTTPMethod:@"POST"
      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                          id result,
                          NSError *error) {

          //show the alert says that message successfully posted in your wall
          [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showAlertFromMainThread:) withObject:error waitUntilDone:NO];

          NSLog(@"\n\nfb post feed error status  = %@", error);
      }];
}
```